# Confirm Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm new to web design, and I have a question about cache.

I have a page called buy-form.php that gets form data from form.php. I want it to have the cache error that makes Google Chrome read "Confirm Form Submission" when the is page accessed manually.

For example, I only want the page to be accessible when form data is submitted. If someone were to type in the page on the address bar, it should have an error.

Comment: You can use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: You've explained what you want, but not what you need from us. Have you tried to do this? Do you have some code and error messages you can share?

Comment: Your understanding of "cache" is incorrect.  When Chrome asks you to "confirm form submission" its because you got that particular page via post, rather than get.  Post is standardly used for submitting data to forms, in order to edit data on the website. Therefore, Chrome is programmed to confirm you wish to resubmit, as trying to edit your data a second time may be a destructive act.  All of this has nothing to do with caching.  This error isn't even necessarily standard to all browsers.  You should be triggering a different error, such as 400 -- bad request, instead.

Answer (score 0):

A javascript `alert("Confirm Form Submission");` can handle your request, and be effective across browsers.  Call a function for the event `<input [other attributes here] onclick=myFunction()>` that has the alert you want.  The alert will stop execution of the page until it is confirmed (selected).  Attach a security code to your form submission and PHP can check for it and `die;` if it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Add this statement to your buy-form.php:

```
if(empty($_POST))
{
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error!');</script>";
}
```

You can replace 'Error!' to whatever you prefer